# Validating youtube Url with channels

Tags: jquery

http://www.youtube.com/channel/UChh-akEbUM8_6ghGVnJd6cQ 
How to validate whether the URL is youtube URL or not?

Comment: Please search for answer on stackowerflow before posting a question.

Comment: Try with Regular Expressions/RegEx.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if URL contains the word "http://www.youtube.com" using `.indexOf()`

```
var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UChh-akEbUM8_6ghGVnJd6cQ';
if (url.indexOf('http://www.youtube.com') > -1) {
  alert( "true");
} else {
  alert( "false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UChh-akEbUM8_6ghGVnJd6cQ";
var isyoutube = /\www\.youtube\.com/.test(url);
```

`isyoutube` gives you `true` or `false` depending if the URL is Youtube or not.

But as someone else already mentioned you should try and find it first. It's so easy to find. 
And also, Youtube has different URLs like http://www.youtu.be so my example will not always work.